# Publish MQTT message in fiware via MQTT Paho library

Tags: python, mqtt, fiware, paho

I am working on this Fiware flow:

[image: Fiware-Flow]

I have used [efrecon/mqtt-client](https://hub.docker.com/r/efrecon/mqtt-client) as MQTT client based on *mosquitto_pub* so that the data can be consumed from Grafana.

```
docker run -it --rm --name mqtt-publisher efrecon/mqtt-client pub -h 172.31.85.246 -p 31624 -m "AGV_Th|25" -t "/ul/5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov/agv001/attrs"
```

In the following example, a key-value pair is sent to populate a persistence with Crate DB and then consumed with Grafana.

[image: Grafana]

I am testing with a new python *mqtt-paho* based client without achieving the same result as with the *mosquitto_pub* based docker client. For instance:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("172.31.85.246", 31624)
client.publish("/ul/5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov/agv001/attrs","{\"agv_th\":65}")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your [network loop](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#network-loop)? Connect returns before the [connection is fully established](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/521) and without a network loop will never finish the process. If you want to connect, publish, then disconnect take a look at [single](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#single).

Comment: You are right, this example does not have a connection loop, I just want the data to be consumed from Grafana. Following your recommendation, I have used single, but I still don't receive the data. Do you think it could be due to how I structure the payload? Thank you.
`publish.single("/ul/5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov/agv001/attrs", "{\"AGV_Th\": '65'}", hostname="172.31.85.246", port=31624)`

Comment: Well the message does differ from your first example; try `"AGV_Th|25"`. If you have access to the broker you can either check it's logs or subscribe to the topic to confirm the message has been processed (I can't really comment on the process after that).

Comment: Thanks. This payload works, properly now: `publish.single("/ul/5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov/agv001/attrs", "AGV_Th|25", hostname="172.31.85.246", port=31624)`

Comment: One more question, in case I want to send several pieces of data, could I use multiple instead of single? In that case, how could be the structure of the message? Thanks

Comment: Read the docs and give it a go, if you can't get it to work, ask another question. One question at a time on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments there were two issues:

- [paho.mqtt.python](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python) requires a [network loop](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#network-loop) for most functions. The `Connect` function returns [before the connection is fully established](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/521) and without a network loop will never finish the process. If you want to connect, publish, then disconnect take a look at [`single`](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#single).
- The message bodies `"{\"agv_th\":65}"` != `"AGV_Th|25"`

`publish.single("/ul/5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov/agv001/attrs", "AGV_Th|25", hostname="172.31.85.246", port=31624)` worked.

[`single`](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#single) and [`multiple`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#multiple) are utility functions that connect, send message(s) and then disconnect. These are useful where you don't want to keep the connection active (or just want to simplify your code). As per the docs you can use `multiple` like this:

```
msgs = [{'topic':"/ul/5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov/agv001/attrs", 'payload':"AGV_Th|25"},
        {'topic':"/ul/5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov/agv00X/attrs", 'payload':"AGV_Th|XX"}]
publish.multiple(msgs, hostname="172.31.85.246", port=31624)
```